# Setting up django static directory for testing/development

Tags: django

In production, the apache server can handle serving `static` files just fine. For testing on my local machine I'm using `manage.py runserver`.

It seems the django apps I have somehow inject some default search paths into this debug server. The browser url shows everything under `/static/whatever`, but those files are coming from all over the place. This is fine for testing but when moving to production I'll need them in the one path. Thankfully, `manage.py collectstatic` provides a handy method to copy everything to the one directory given by `STATIC_ROOT` in `settings.py`. I've set mine to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')` where `BASE_DIR` is where `manage.py` is.

Now I want to start adding my own stuff in `static`, but everything's still being hosted by these hidden search directories provided by apps under `DEBUG=True`. I've tried the following in `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

and

```
import re
from django.conf import settings
if settings.DEBUG:
    static_url = re.escape(settings.STATIC_URL.lstrip('/'))
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % static_url, 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    )
```

Neither have worked.

I tried providing my static directory in `STATICFILES_DIRS`, but get the error `ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting`. So then I tried removing my `STATIC_ROOT` so the path was only given in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Finally I can access my files in development (still with `staticfiles_urlpatterns` from above).

**However**, I'm pretty sure removing `STATIC_ROOT` is *not* the right way to go about it. For a start, I won't be able to run `collectstatic` after installing other apps without manually changing everything around again. *How should I be configuring my static directory for development?*

Also, is there a way to turn off hosting app specific static directories so I can make sure my single static is set up correctly (but still be in development mode)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making this more complex than it needs to be. Include "static" in `STATICFILES_DIRS` as you are doing, for the project-level assets, but make `STATIC_ROOT` - ie the destination of the `collectstatic` command - something else, probably "staticfiles", and alias that directory to `/static/` in Apache. Django will serve your assets from STATICFILES_DIRS automatically, without you even needing to add the urlpatterns.

Comment: Excellent, so is `STATIC_ROOT` purely for `collectstatic` and not used in production?

Comment: Well, it's used by the staticfiles app as a whole, but yes.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I completely missed the point here.

1. `STATIC_ROOT` is for `collectstatic` to pool all the static content for you. **You don't add your files to here** because it gets overwritten.
2. Now for production you can get your webserver to host the directory `STATIC_ROOT` and point `STATIC_URL` to the url it can be found through the webserver.
3. `STATICFILES_DIRS` allows you to add your own directories for `collectstatic` to search and pool to `STATIC_ROOT`. Then you can nicely separate static stuff for each of your apps and/or a common project static.
4. For dev, django expects everything to be in `STATICFILES_DIRS` and hosts that, not `STATIC_ROOT` because then there would be duplicates. This makes sense for larger projects because you want to be working on the per-app files, not some blob of stuff for a website.